# why would a boolean revert to an original value?

Tags: vba, vb6, boolean

I know this might be a more of a general question, but I've looked at my code a 100 times and am not sure what's wrong. I set a global flag so that it can be used in different forms of my application.

```
Dim OverPopulated as Boolean
```

I have a function where I first set it to FALSE, and after it goes through some validating it gets set to TRUE.

Now i do a bunch of stuff, go through different forms, and the value stays correct the entire time. Basically I need this value for another form, so when I check

```
if OverPopulated = false then
   MsgBox "You Can't do this and that"
   exit sub
End if
```

Then all of the sudden it gets set to FALSE. I've went through every instance of OVERPOPULATED in my application and put a break point to it to make sure that nowhere do i set it to FALSE, except for the one time I set it to FALSE before my validation.

I only have it in 2 other forms in my applications. There is one place where the flag is being run twice through the same statement (just like the one above). The first time it goes through, the value is correct, then it goes through again and the value is set to FALSE.

Any ideas? if this is too vague, please let me know, I'll try to edit it.

EDIT: I deleted a lot of the code but here's how it looks.....

```
Dim OverPopulated as Boolean
```

' modular level

```
Private Sub ValidatePopulation()

Dim admDate as date

OverPopulated = False

admDate = Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yyyy")


Select Case revPURP
    Case 0, 1, 2
    'Check make sure these fields 
    'some if statements, checking, validation

    Case Else ' no need to do a 
End Select

OverPopulated = True 'I MAKE SURE IT GETS HERE and is set to TRUE!!!

End sub
```

Now, in other functions I used it like this...

```
If OverPopulated = False Then
    If optStat (0).Value = True Or optStat (1).Value = True Then
        MsgBox "You are not able to do this”, vbCritical, "Incorrect review status...."
        TabPop.Tab = 6
    End If
    Exit sub
Else
    'Proceed with SAVE
End If
```

So I have this. and I have another statement just like this somewhere else. This one gets hit twice. The first time I go through it line by line and it's FALSE, then the 2nd time around the value is TRUE.

Comment: VB6 at any rate had a fantastic feature where you could set a breakpoint when a variable value changed.  That would be handy to find where/when/why it allegedly changes back

Comment: Is the code that encompasses `OverPopluated` too large to post here?

Comment: @MattCremeens let me try to show you this...

Comment: @MattCremeens Please see edit

Comment: Where does the code live?  Is it inside a class, a module?  Are your 2 snippets of code inside the same source file?  Make sure you have `Option Explicit` declared at the top of all your source files.

Comment: I wonder by dimensioning it locally if you are overriding the global dim. What if you take out the `Dim OverPopulated as Boolean` and just left in your original `Global OverPopulated as Boolean`?

Comment: @Matt: I assumed that `Dim OverPopulated as Boolean` was the global variable declaration.  Is `Global OverPopulated as Boolean` even valid syntax?  I've never seen that before.

Comment: @sstan it is valid syntax, but I like your suggestion to make sure `Option Explicit` is the first line of code.

Comment: @Matt: Then I think we are both suspecting the same thing: that, one way or another, OP is actually using 2 different `OverPopulated` variables.

Comment: Im using dim, not global my mistake. The code lives inside one form, i will eventually need it make it a global to be used by multiple forms

Comment: The code in edit is what it looks like, except the dim boolean is set at a modular level and i have option explicit

Comment: When `OverPopulated` gets reset are other Globals also reset?

Comment: As @Plutonix suggested in very first comment, set a watch on expression `Overpopulated` and have it break when it changes value

Comment: There is no `Global` keyword in VB6. We use `Public`.

Comment: The `DIM` has to be at the top of the module, not in a code block. If functions that use it are not in that module then it must be `Public Dim`

Comment: @noodles it is at the top, i set it at modular level so i can use it throughout the form. It works fine, theres a value but it changes

Comment: Your question shows it is enclosed within a procedure. Because there is code without a sub or function definition after it. Fix your question.

Comment: So `OverPopulated = False` is only set once (in `ValidatePopulation') though it is also False by default and that Sub is only called once. And you're certain it is only declared once? And somehow after using it several times (with a value of True), it gets set back to False? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I set it to FALSE, then once it passes the Validating, it gets set to True. I'd this this flag in 2 places only. In one place it works fine the first time it hits the function, but then after it goes through the same function again it was getting set to FALSE when the value was still true. Not sure what was going on, but setting the OverPopulated as Global fixed the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like for some reason the value was getting reset to FALSE. I took out the Dim OverPopulated as Boolean from my form code, and placed it in a GLOBAL module where all the other globals are stored. This seems to have fixed the issue of the value remaining the same while I'm manuevering in the application. Thank you for all your comments.

```
Global OverPopulated as Boolean
```

Comment: Ah. I thought you said it was already in a module rather than form!